# Eclipse RCP. How to change method in org.eclipse.ui.internal

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

How to change implementation method?

```
IStatus restoreState()
```

in class:

```
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, internal classes are out of bounds - [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html).

The method `restoreState` does not even exist in the Eclipse 4.3 version of `Workbench`.

Comment: Perhaps if you tell us what you are trying to do there may be a supported method of doing it.